Are the representations appearing from a series of bundle reductions independent of the order of those reductions?
Given some princpal bundle, I know that the order of bundle reductions doesn't matter w.r.t. the final structure  group we end up with.  Is the same true of the representations we end up with if we start with a particular one?
Maybe there are some conditions, for example if the reductions are injective Lie group homomorphisms?
